# 3ware 9500S-4LP raid-1 rebuild failed

Tags: 3ware, storage

After replacment of 2 failed drives on 3ware card i got this:

```
Ctl   Model        (V)Ports  Drives   Units   NotOpt  RRate   VRate  BBU
------------------------------------------------------------------------
c0    9500S-4LP    4         4        4       2       5       5      -        
c1    9500S-4LP    4         4        2       1       1       1      -
```

On controler c0 insted of 4 drives 2 units i got 4 units and,

```
Unit  UnitType  Status         %RCmpl  %V/I/M  Stripe  Size(GB)  Cache  AVrfy
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
u0    RAID-1    DEGRADED       -       -       -       931.312   OFF    OFF    
u1    RAID-1    DEGRADED       -       -       -       1862.63   OFF    OFF    
u2    JBOD      OK             -       -       -       1863.02   OFF    OFF    
u3    JBOD      OK             -       -       -       931.513   OFF    OFF    

Port   Status           Unit   Size        Blocks        Serial
---------------------------------------------------------------
p0     OK               u2     1.82 TB     3907029168    WD-229813     
p1     OK               u1     1.82 TB     3907029168    WD-409824     
p2     OK               u0     931.51 GB   1953525168    5VP39Y            
p3     OK               u3     931.51 GB   1953525168    WD-806869
```

After some searching, all that i can see is that i would need to recreate all units, but that sound like a bad idea, i would appreciate any advice.

My question is, why are my two new disks shown as JBOD and how can i import them into u0 and u1?

Comment: Just make the small one a hot spare. Wait for it to get added. Then make the large one a hot spare.